# Get image from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avcapturesession

I'm essentially cloning [Cropping a captured image exactly to how it looks in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924255/cropping-a-captured-image-exactly-to-how-it-looks-in-avcapturevideopreviewlayer) since asking the original poster if they found a solution isn't an "answer" and I am unable to comment yet because I don't have enough reputation...

The app I'm building will always be in portrait mode because rotation isn't important in this case.
I have an AVCaptureSession with the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer connected to a UIView of size 320x240 that is positioned against the top layout guide.

I have capturing the input working but the image that I'm receiving is skewed and shows a lot more than the portion I'm displaying. How can I capture just the area that is shown in my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` s

```
-(CGRect)metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:(CGRect)layerRect
```

This method lets you easily convert the visible CGRect of your layer to the actual camera output.

One caveat: The physical camera is not mounted "top side up", but rather rotated 90 degrees to the right. (So if you hold your iPhone - Home Button right, the camera is actually top side up).

Keeping this in mind, you have to convert the CGRect the above method gives you, to crop the image to exactly what is on screen.

Example:

```
CGRect visibleLayerFrame = THE ACTUAL VISIBLE AREA IN THE LAYER FRAME
CGRect metaRect = [self.previewView.layer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:visibleLayerFrame];


CGSize originalSize = [originalImage size];

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(_snapInterfaceOrientation)) {
    // For portrait images, swap the size of the image because
    // here, the output image is actually rotated relative to what you see on screen.

    CGFloat temp = originalSize.width;
    originalSize.width = originalSize.height;
    originalSize.height = temp;
}

// metaRect is fractional, that's why we multiply here

CGRect cropRect;

cropRect.origin.x = metaRect.origin.x * originalSize.width;
cropRect.origin.y = metaRect.origin.y * originalSize.height;
cropRect.size.width = metaRect.size.width * originalSize.width;
cropRect.size.height = metaRect.size.height * originalSize.height;

cropRect = CGRectIntegral(cropRect);
```

This may be a bit confusing, but what made me really understand this is this:

Hold your device "Home Button right" -> You'll see the x - axis actually lies along the "height" of your iPhone, while the y - axis lies along the "width" of your iPhone. That's why for portrait images, you have to swap the size ;)